# Does Pokemon Steel Sun/Moon come with 200 pokeballs OR a steel case?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I thought that Pokemon Sun & Moon Steelbook came with a "collectible Steelbook case" and 200 Poke Balls, but I got it today (preorder from Amazon), and it had a Steelbook case, but no 200 Poke Balls?

Is this an either/or promotion?

I see that

- [EB GAMES](https://www.ebgames.ca/3DS/Games/725880/pokemon-sun-and-moon-dual-pack) has it with 200 pokeballs, and
- [Amazon](https://www.amazon.ca/Pokemon-Dual-Pack-Nintendo-Steel/dp/B01IBZKJBK/ref=sr_1_1?s=videogames&ie=UTF8&qid=1479502964&sr=1-1&keywords=pokemon+steelbook) has it with a "collectible Steelbook case"

Are there any other ways promos for buying it?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that it didn't come with the code for 200 pokeballs? In the Q&A on the Amazon page, users said it had the code in it.

Comment: I've double checked it, and don't see it there... It does say "BONUS: Includes a SteelBook Game Case" on the box, but no mention of the 200 Poke Balls, and I don't see anything in either game's box, either.

Comment: That's odd. If that's the case, then maybe the Steelbook edition is the only dual pack that doesn't get the 200 balls.

Comment: In Italy we get a download code for 12 Quick Ball. Amazing, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is an either/or promotion. You got the better one IMO, since [Amazon had a free steelbook and 20% off](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/558lwy/sunmoon_dual_pack_comes_with_code_for_200_free/d88pbvk/) and is now [worth more than double](https://www.amazon.ca/Pokemon-Dual-Pack-Nintendo-Steel/dp/B01IBZKJBK/ref=sr_1_1?s=videogames&ie=UTF8&qid=1479502964&sr=1-1&keywords=pokemon%20steelbook) the original selling price.

Also, it's not a lump-sum of 200 Pokeballs but [2 codes of 100 Pokeballs each](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/558lwy/sunmoon_dual_pack_comes_with_code_for_200_free/d88tx40/) (to be used in each game).

As for other promotions, I don't think it's possible to have an exhaustive list given the worldwide release. [GameStop had a double-sided poster as a preorder bonus](http://nintenfan.com/3ds/gamestop-offering-pokemon-sun-moon-double-sided-poster-pre-orders.html), but that's all I know of.